# How to get props variable in detailed props React-Native

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, arguments, components, arrow-functions

I have a custom component like this

```
const MyCustomComponent = ({ value, style }) => {
   // I can access value & style with value and style
   return <View style={style}>
      <Text>{value}</Text>
   </View>
}
```

I can called it with

```
<MyCustomComponent value="123" style={{ color: "blue" }} />
```

My question is how to get arguments or alyelse to get all props passed to my component?

In native function, i can use `arguments` to get allProps as an Array and set it in a new variable like `const allProps = arguments[0]`

What about in arrow function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is a functional component, it is built as such that it only receives one object - that is props. When you did this: `const MyComponent({value, style})` you destructured the prop object, extracting only the two variables.

You should instead do this:

```
const MyCustomComponent = (props) => {

 //you can access the values like this
 console.log(props.style, props.value)

 //or you can access them like this which is the same thing you did 
 //earlier  
 const {style, value} = props;
 console.log(style, value)

 return (
  ...
 )

}
```

Keep in mind that you need to have React in scope, so be sure to import it at the top:

```
import React from 'react';
```

Functional components are very well explained in React documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get 'value' and 'style' props using a single variable?

You can use:

```
const MyCustomComponent = (props) => {
   // I can access value & style with value and style
   return <View style={props.style}>
      <Text>{props.value}</Text>
   </View>
}
```